# Twig renders nothing

Tags: php, twig

I am using composer to install twig/twig : 1.65.  On a windows box running xampp with PHP 5.5.

This is my work development box and everything acts as expected, usually.  However, When I try to run even a trivial script using twig, I get nothing rendered, no error messages, either on the screen or in the logs (display errors is on).  I have successfully used twig in a Symfony2 project on this same machine, but I'm trying it standalone for a different project.  Below is what I'm trying to run.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

$twig->render('Hello {{ name }} !', array('name' => 'Eidsonator'));
```

I'm trying to actually run something when templates, but I get the same result using the above script.  When I trying to render a template, I changed the name of the template, to see if it would generate an error, and it did.  I got something along the lines of `Twig cannot find the template blah.blah.blah`

I did have this working at home last night on a Linux box, following the same steps.

What am I missing?  What are some more debugging steps I can try?

Comment: windows running XAMPP -> everything acts as expected, usually -> LIES! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`render()` method **DOES NOT** `echo` its results, so you have to do that explicitly:

```
echo $twig->render(...);
```

Comment: ahhh!  What a stupid mistake!  I was looking at error logs, invoking the debugger, uninstalled and reinstalled twig.  I think it's time for a cup of coffee.  Thanks.

Comment: I feel like "render" is an odd choice of word, in this case. "render" implies to "show".

Comment: @AnalogWeapon it does not. Render makes an artifact from sources. How you use it - is out of the scope of the term.

Comment: @zerkms I suppose it depends on the definition. It can mean to "make by" (Like rendering fat from meat), but I feel like when it's used in the context of a templating system (A system for visual presentation), the "to show" form of render comes to mind more readily. Oh well. No biggy.